# Wordpress add_filter not working

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

I have declared filter in the Wordpress plugin

```
$full_filename = apply_filters ( 'ses_wpscd_scheduled_export_filename', $folder . $filename);
```

and I have try to change 'folder' output value to something else using add_filter using function below

```
add_filter('ses_wpscd_scheduled_export_filename', 'new_wpscd_scheduled_export_filename',11,1);
function new_wpscd_scheduled_export_filename($val)
{

    $newdir = '/home/testcom/public_html/orders/daily/';
    $olddir = '/home/testcom/public_html/wp-content/uploads/ses_wpscd/';
    $val = str_replace($old, $newdir, $val );
    return $val;
}
```

but somehow it comes with an old folder anyway.

Any tips? For me it is a first add_fiter so I maybe I did something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('ses_wpscd_scheduled_export_filename', 'new_wpscd_scheduled_export_filename', 11);

function new_wpscd_scheduled_export_filename($val) {
    return str_replace( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/ses_wpscd/' , '/home/testcom/public_html/orders/daily/', $val );
}
```